# common axis subplots with plot.ly for R

Tags: r, plotly

I am attempting to use subplots with the `plot.ly` R library for interactive online charting. I can successfully create a subplot, however am struggling to only have a single y-axis that is common to both charts.

The `plot.ly` website does provide an example for a common x-axis, however this is done slightly differently using and additional `trace` rather than the `group` option that is provided within the `plot_ly()` function.

example code:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)
dt <- data.table(x = c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"),
                 y = c(12,4,3,9,5,10,3,7),
                 group = factor(c(rep("G1",4),rep("G2",4))))
dt$id <- as.integer(dt$group)
xx <- xaxis_standard
yy <- yaxis_standard
p <- plot_ly(dt, x=x, y=y, group = group, xaxis = paste0("x",id)) 
p <- layout(p, yaxis = list(range = c(0, max(y))))
p <- subplot(p, margin = 0.05) 
p <- layout(p,showlegend = F, yaxis = list(anchor = 'x1'))
p
```

This image shows what results when I execute the code.
[image: Plot.ly subplot chart]

What I would like to have is the same chart, however without the y-axis on the right hand subplot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subplots are on separate axes labeled `xaxis2`, `yaxis2`, etc. Those axes are also arguments to `layout()`.

```
p <- layout(p, showlegend = F, yaxis = list(anchor = 'x1'), 
            yaxis2 = list(showticklabels = F))
p
```

[image]